# What difference would it make to nest my script (inluding functions) inside a function from writing code in .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand the difference between writing PowerShell scripts in two different "styles" -- I guess that what this would be called?

**1** .ps1

```
<#
#>
function functionOne {
# Do something.
}

function functionTwo {
# Do something.
}

if (something) {
# Do something.
}
```

**2** .ps1

```
<#
 #>
function bigFunction {
    function smallFunction1 {}
    function samallFunction2 {}

}
```

Now, I guess for 2, I need to export bigFunction to be able to use it outside?

Comment: The difference is that the functions inside `bigFunction` will be private to that scope however, if this is going to be a module, you can export specific functions and don't need to have all the helper / private functions inside the main one

Comment: And both of them need to be called by dot-sourcing then followed by path?

Comment: You mean both scripts? If you want to load the functions on a different scope, yes.

Comment: when would I opt for a module instead of script? and how do I  invoke it in powershell?

Comment: @jsnoobie Here's a minimal module template, to get started https://gist.github.com/ninmonkey/cf307b373e4e5e211f3be7d6ee2d15b4